# Why is this angular filter not working

Tags: angularjs

I am building a basic forum app.

A forum has many topics. A topic has many posts. A post has a ThreadId property.

I am loading up a forum object with topics and posts. (I will eventually load posts from topics.)

I want to initially hide all the posts and then show the relevant ones when a ThreadId is passed in. I am doing something wrong, my filter isn't working ( all records are showing)

In my controller

```
// setup default filter
$scope.filters = { ThreadId: 2 };
```

Html

```
 <div ng-repeat="post in topic.Posts | filter : filters.ThreadId" >
```

Comment: I believe what you want is filter: {ThreadId: filters.ThreadId}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only pass `filters` object, it will filter by ThreadId in the array.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in topic.Posts | filter : filters" >
```